# defaultLocale of AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver is not working

Tags: java, spring, locale

I added AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver.

```java
@Configuration
public class ApplicationContextConfig {
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver localeResolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.KOREA); // ko_KR

        return localeResolver;
    }
}
```

But when I get locale from http request without accept-language header, it returns locale of my system.

```java
public class CustomIntercepterAdapter extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
    request.getHeader("accept-language"); // null
    request.getLocale().toString(); // en_KR;
  }
}
```

Why the defaultLocale is not working?

Comment: what's the value of request.getHeader("Accept-Language")?

Comment: @clevertension It's `null`

Answer (score 0):

the value of **request.getLocale()** is determined by your web container such as **Tomcat**, so spring localeResolver can't not affect this value. this value is **Locale.getDefault()**,
if you want to change your default locale, you can add one more code

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationContextConfig {
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver localeResolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.KOREA); // ko_KR
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.KOREA);

        return localeResolver;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

clevertension's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57620522/4287124) states the right reason why your code does not work, but the problem is somewhere else. `request.getLocale()` only returns the value from your Accept-Language header, or if none supplied, the system default (as clearly explained in [the docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocale())). You are looking for `LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()` instead. It returns the locale resolved by Spring using the resolver you supply (in which you configured the default locale to be Korean).

So your code should look like this:

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
    request.getHeader("accept-language"); // null
    LocaleContextHolder.getLocale(); // should evaluate to "kr";
}
```